# What font is this? I've used all the websites to find out

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I found this image online and I am looking to recreate this diploma however with a separate name and degree. Obviously I know that it's not going to be legitimate degree, I just want to do it for giggles. I've searched all the most common websites but since maybe it's not the best quality image, it's really difficult to find. If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated, thank you!!

I've used

WhatTheFont
Identifont
Serif-Font Identification Guide
WhatFontIs
Fontspring Matcherator

Answer (score 1):

As you said, quite difficult to identify this font from this picture but it definitely looks like **Trajan Pro** to me.

edit : It seems Trajan is referenced in their "brand & identity guidelines" [here](https://visualidentity.columbia.edu/content/typography-3)

Comment: It’s a very far cry from Trajan. They are completely different styles; just look at M and R, for example.

Comment: thank you! perhaps a silly question, is all the type in this picture the same font?

Comment: this is so hard, I can't find anything :/

Comment: @user477465 All the text seems to be the same font, but it’s not Trajan. On newer diplomas they do use Trajan, but this is an older one.

Comment: @user477465  Janus is right, L and R brackets are completely different. This font also seems to be more condensed. it is not Trajan (my bad). You could customize it a from a Trajan base tho.

Comment: @A90 is there any other font I can use? and how can I customize trajan base